# jenkins running cypress cannot permission denied, mkdir '/.npmcess

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

How can I run cypress in Jenkins Pipeline?

I have try this:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
      docker {
      image 'cypress/base:10'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.io/xxx/test-scripts'
      }
    }
    stage('Dependencies') {
        steps {
            sh 'npm ci'
            sh 'npm run cy:verify'
        }
    }
    stage('Tests') {
        steps {
            sh 'npm run test'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

but get this error :  `Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'` at Dependencies?